# Unable to compile and package software due to "cannot create directory" error

Tags: apt, software-compilation

I tried to compile and package `snownews` and `deadbeef` to `DEB` files for my Raspberry Pi OS:

```
sudo auto-apt ./configure
sudo checkinstall
```

And it's failed. Here is the result it returns:

#### From `snownews`

```
========================= Installation results ===========================
Installing /usr/local/share/man/man1/snownews.1 ...
install: cannot create directory '/usr/local/share/man': No such file or directory
make: *** [man/Module.mk:18: /usr/local/share/man/man1/snownews.1] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

#### From `deadbeef`

```
========================= Installation results ===========================
Making install in pixmaps
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/deadbeef-1.8.4/pixmaps'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/deadbeef-1.8.4/pixmaps'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/deadbeef/pixmaps'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/share/deadbeef’: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [Makefile:455: install-pixmapsDATA] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/deadbeef-1.8.4/pixmaps'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:524: install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/deadbeef-1.8.4/pixmaps'
make: *** [Makefile:822: install-recursive] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

I tried to Google the error message, however it is too vague that I couldn't get the answer I need. It only said that it couldn't create directory. But I have run with the highest privilege (`sudo`) and it still said it couldn't? I don't really know what to do next.

My main goal is package the software so I can manage it with `apt`. The reason I would like it is because I don't know if the next update of the software requires me to remove the old version or not. So I try my best to keep everything as neat as possible.

So far what I did/knew:

1. The source `dir` is in my home dir.
2. `sudo` was used during the compiling process
3. `deadbeef` source [was compiled for ARMHF once](https://debian.pkgs.org/sid/multimedia-main-armhf/deadbeef_1.8.4-dmo2_armhf.deb.html), so I'm pretty sure that the source supports this architecture.
4. `snownews` is unsure.
5. I have success compiling & packaging alpine software. So I don't think this is the `checkinstall` fault.

Comment: deb files is normally installed with `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file` and then 
`sudo apt-get install -f` alternative with `sudo apt install ./name.deb` . Have you tried that?

Comment: The complaints are that a directory does not exist. Do they exist? What does `ls /usr/local/share` produce? Do the compiles go through after you've `mkdir -p  /usr/local/share/man/man1`?

Comment: @LjmDullaart with `ls /usr/local/share` it produces `ca-certificates  fonts`. And when I created the dir, it passed but... it still kept printing dir error with a new dir path (`/usr/local/share/man/de`). So I don't think this could solve the problem because I don't exactly know how many dirs it need to create. (Shouldn't it be able to create programtically?)

Comment: @MatsKarlsson I think you get wrong idea. My case was I have no deb package, so I need to compile sources to deb packages. And I couldn't do that because the `cannot create directory` error.

Comment: The problem is, that the creator of the program/package/... has apparently a number of directories on his machine and doesn't bother to verify that those directories are available  during the config-phase. Happens a lot. So, yes, that can be seen as a bug in the creation of the package.  However, the number of directories that are used should be limited, so you should be able, in just a few runs, to create all of them. Your other option is to contact the creator/maintainer and wait until he releases an updated package.

Comment: @LjmDullaart So what I found is a bug and a quick solution is create all the requirement dir, right? Thanks you very much :D

Comment: A bug is perhaps a bit harsh, carelessness is a better word. Anyway, the bug is in the installation/compile process, not in the software itself. It may also be, the the software has some prerequisites, that are not on your system. These could have created the directories.

Comment: @LjmDullaart If the softwaree has some dependencies, is there anyway I can figure it out? The error message didn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

In any sane world, these commands will compile and package `snownews`:

First install `debmake` and package specific dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -y install debmake
sudo apt-get -y install libxml2-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Retrieve the latest master branch from github and rename it
with a numeric version number (today's date is OK):

```
wget https://github.com/kouya/snownews/archive/master.tar.gz
tar zxf master.tar.gz
mv snownews-master snownews-20200915
tar zcf snownews-20200915.tar.gz snownews-20200915
rm master.tar.gz
```

Debianize the package:

```
cd snownews-20200915
debmake
debuild
```

However, this fails in the `debuild` step because the Makefile installs files in non-standard places or ignores the `DESTDIR` environment variable that `debuild` uses to install the package under a temporary directory. It's an exercise for the reader to fix the configuration that causes this (and send a pull request to the original author).